# Is there a name for "loopback teaching" technique (explaining something to yourself to learn it)?

Tags: learning, speech

Here's the description of a process which I call "loopback teaching":

1. First, I learn something the "normal" way, e.g. by reading or watching.
2. I imagine a person or multiple people which I think may be interested in the topic. If there are no such people I know of, I just imagine I'm reading a lecture to some abstract audience.
3. I explain the topic in a way I would do that in real life. I can imagine some kind of presentation (with slides or on a whiteboard), which I go through in a sequence, mostly without skipping. I use my internal speech in mostly the same way I do that when speaking out loud in real life in similar situations.

I noticed I started doing this back when I was at school, and much later I found out that other people use different forms of this technique, or something very similar.

There are multiple related things I know of:

- [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or generally explaining something to inanimate object
- [Learning by teaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_by_teaching), or generally explaining something you wish to learn to another people

My questions are:

1. Is there a name for this study technique?
2. Is this related to speech internalization? If so, how? Is there any studies on that subject? In the example above I internalize a dialogue instead of a monologue, and this seems similar to how children internalize their private monologue at the age of 7 years (if I'm not mistaken).